# ¿cómo agrupar ciertos elementos de una lista?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter, ipython

¡Hola!

Solicito ayuda para mi programa, tengo una lista de elementos, por ejemplo:

```
       cadena = ['X','Y','X','X','Y','s','u','b',':','Y','X','Y','i','t','e','m',':','X','X','Y']
```

quiero un algoritmo donde pueda seleccionar sólo los caracteres 'X' y 'Y', y guardarlos en cada entrada de una lista, pero no como caracteres separados sino como un string, el resultado debe ser así:

```
       sub_cadenas = ['XYXXY','YXY','XXY]
```

los caracteres diferentes de 'X' y 'Y' pueden ser borrados u olvidados, no importan, lo único que importa es que separan los strings.

Ya intenté el siguiente código:

```
    string = ''
    sub_cadenas = []
    for j in cadena:
         if j == 'X':
             string +=j  
         elif j == 'Y':
             string += j
         else:
             sub_cadenas.append(string)
             break
```

pero solo logro guardar el primer string

```
      'XYXXY'
```

:(

No sé como regresar a la cadena, pero desde la posición cadena[5] e implementar nuevamente el loop.

Saludos!

Comment: El comando break hace que finalice el for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por añadir otro modo, se puede hacer agrupando las letras similares:

```
from itertools import groupby

cadena = ['X','Y','X','X','Y','s','u','b',':','Y',
         'X','Y','i','t','e','m',':','X','X','Y']

chars = "XY"

sub_cadenas = ["".join(g) 
              for (v,g) in groupby(cadena, key=lambda x: x in chars)
              if v]
```

En `groupby` se utiliza como clave de agrupamiento una expresión lambda, dividiendo la lista en grupos afines y contrarios:

```
groupby(cadena, key=lambda x: x in chars) -->

(True, ['X', 'Y', 'X', 'X', 'Y']
(False, ['s', 'u', 'b', ':']
(True, ['Y', 'X', 'Y']
(False, ['i', 't', 'e', 'm', ':']
(True, ['X', 'X', 'Y']
```

Filtrando por el primer valor se obtienen los grupos que nos interesa.

Answer (score 4):

Una forma bien compacta usando expresiones regulares

```
import re

cadena = ['X','Y','X','X','Y','s','u','b',':','Y','X','Y','i','t','e','m',':','X','X','Y']

lista = re.findall('[XY]+', "".join(cadena))
print(lista)

['XYXXY', 'YXY', 'XXY']
```

Explicación:

- En primer lugar usamos `join(cadena)` para armar un string de  la lista
- Luego la expresión regular `[XY]+` para encontrar cualquier grupo de `X` o `Y` y mediante `re.findall()` recuperar una lista con todos los casos.

**Nota**: ten en cuenta que el patrón de búsqueda es sensible a mayusculas y minúsculas, `x` e `y` no serán consideradas. Si quieres considerar las dos versiones, podrías usar este `[XYxy]+` patrón.

Comment: No conocía *re* , wow muchas gracias!!! De hecho si necesito distinguir entre mayusculas y minúsculas, me servirá mucho esta paquetería. Gracias!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Para no alterar mucho tu trabajo, le agregue una bandera de control y le quite el break.

```
string = ''
sub_cadenas = []
bandxy = 0
i = 0
cant = len(cadena)

for j in cadena:
    i += 1
    if j == 'X':
        string +=j
        bandxy = 1
        if i != cant: continue 
    elif j == 'Y':
        string += j
        bandxy = 1
        if i != cant: continue 
    if bandxy == 1 :
        #print (string)
        sub_cadenas.append(string)
        string = ''
        bandxy = 0
print (sub_cadenas)
```

Comment: La variable i controla el ultimo elemento.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! Ya lo entendí, me has dado herramientas para seguir trabajando, en serio te lo agradezco!!

Answer (score 1):

Tienes varios problemas:

- El `break` ocasiona que el `for` termine en cuanto se encuentra un carácter que no sea 'X' o 'Y'.
- Aunque elimines el `break` no vas a conseguir las subcadenas separadas si no reinicias la variable `string` cada vez que realizas el `append`. Además, para evitar que se añadan cadenas vacías debes comprobar que `string` no sea tal.
- Concatenar cadenas es muy ineficiente dado que son inmutables. Cada vez que añades un carácter se crea un nuevo objeto por tanto. En su lugar deberías usar una lista temporal y luego aplicar `str.join` para obtener la cadena de ella.

Siguiendo tu idea original y teniendo lo anterior en cuanta podrías hacer:

```
sub_cadenas = []

subcadena = []
for c in cadena:
    if c == 'X' or c == "Y":
        subcadena.append(c)
    else:
        if subcadena:
            sub_cadenas.append("".join(subcadena))
            subcadena = []
if subcadena:
    sub_cadenas.append("".join(subcadena))
```